# Como salvar arquivos em servidor separados por extensão

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um `WEB API` que recebe um arquivo via `POST` segue o código do `Controller`:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
  {
        // Ver se POST é MultiPart? 
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        // Preparar CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider para carga de dados
        // (veja mais abaixo)

        string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/Uploads");
        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            // Ler conteúdo da requisição para CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider. 
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
            }
            // OK se tudo deu certo.
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

Meu método: `CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider`

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider :     MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) 
        : base(path) { }
    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
    }
}
```

Estou salvando os arquivos em uma pasta *Arquivos/Uploads* porém, eu preciso salvar os arquivos que são recebidos em pastas separadas, por exemplo *Word* em uma pasta chamada *Word* etc...

A forma que estou fazendo agora está meio burocrática mas funciona. Tenho uma classe Utilitários que após o recebimento do arquivo ele faz uma cópia do arquivo para a pasta em que ela deveria ficar e apaga o arquivo dentro da pasta *Arquivos/Uploads*.

Existe uma forma de simplificar isso, que através do `controller Post` eu identifico a extensão do arquivo e salve ele na respectiva pasta no servidor?

Comment: O nome da pasta é exatamente igual a extensão? A pasta já está criada ou deverá ser criada caso não exista?

Comment: Até então eu criei algumas pastas com as extensões mais conhecidas, e tinha pensado em deixar as que não são tão conhecidas em uma pasta "Outros". Porém é interessante essa abordagem, para criar a pasta caso não exista.

Comment: Renan, você esqueceu da primeira pergunta. O nome da pasta será o mesmo da extensão?

Comment: Verdade, sim o mesmo nome.

Comment: Esse `CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider` é algo que você criou ou alguma lib externa?

Comment: Eu implentei ele, editei a pergunta e o inseri. Para salvar o nome do arquivo. Vi em uma resposta aqui no PT-SO http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153255/61561

Comment: Como está o código da sua classe utilitária?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não irei entrar em detalhes sobre o `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`. Poderia ser algo um pouco extenso, então irei mostrar apenas como modificar o seu código para fazer o que deseja.

Primeiro, como você deseja criar uma pasta com o nome da extensão caso não exista, você precisará criar o método para isso. Para simplificar, pode utilizar o método abaixo:

```
private String CriarDiretorioSeNaoExistir(string path)
    {
        var returnPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

        if (!Directory.Exists(returnPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));

        return returnPath;
    }
```

Ele simplesmente verifica se o diretório existe. Se não existir ele criará. E como retorno ele devolve o caminho completo, ou seja, o seu `fileSaveLocation`.

Após isso, apenas moveremos o arquivo salvo para o novo diretório, desta forma:

```
File.Move(file.LocalFileName,
           Path.Combine(CriarDiretorioSeNaoExistir(Path.Combine("~/Arquivos/Uploads", file.LocalFileName.Split('.').LastOrDefault())),
           file.LocalFileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault()));
```

Dessa forma estamos obtendo o arquivo salvo com o `file.LocalFileName` e movendo para a nova pasta (o que vem após a vírgula). E no mesmo método já estamos verificando e criando o diretório caso não exista (fique à vontade para separar caso ache necessário).

Seu código completo ficará desta forma:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    // Ver se POST é MultiPart? 
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
    // Preparar CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider para carga de dados
    // (veja mais abaixo)

    string fileSaveLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/Uploads");
    CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileSaveLocation);
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        // Ler conteúdo da requisição para CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider. 
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            files.Add(Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName));
              File.Move(file.LocalFileName,
                    Path.Combine(CriarDiretorioSeNaoExistir(Path.Combine("~/Arquivos/Uploads", file.LocalFileName.Split('.').LastOrDefault())),
                    file.LocalFileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault()));
        }
        // OK se tudo deu certo.
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}


private String CriarDiretorioSeNaoExistir(string path)
{
    var returnPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

    if (!Directory.Exists(returnPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));

    return returnPath;
}
```